# Tutorial: How to boot debug a VirtualBox Windows virtual machine using WinDbg / KD?

Tags: windows, debugging, virtual-machine, virtualbox, remote-debugging

This question is for the purpose of giving a tutorial on how to boot debug a VirtualBox Windows virtual machine using WinDbg / KD

Answer (score 3):

[Boot debugging does not work with VirtualKD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67103102/7194773), so you need to create the pipe manually

1. On the guest do:

```
bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /bootdebug on
bcdedit /bootdebug {bootmgr} on
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} debugtype serial
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} baudrate 115200
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} debugport 1 
bcdedit /set debugtype serial
bcdedit /set baudrate 115200
bcdedit /set debugport 1
```

I think `bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport:1 baudrate:115200` is a shortcut that is another way of achieving what the latter 6 achieve

2. Shut down the guest
3. Go to virtual machine settings -> serial ports -> enable serial port -> COM1 -> Host Pipe and then type the name of the pipe to create `\\.\pipe\PipeName`. Uncheck connect to an existing pipe.
4. On WinDbg, go to File -> Kernel Debug -> COM. Select Pipe and type `\\.\pipe\PipeName` into port, and select reconnect, and ok.
5. Start the VM
6. The debugger will connect but will not break. If it doesn't connect (debuggee is not connected) then restart the VM -- I restart on the start menu.
7. When it connects and it will say 'debuggee is running' when on the desktop. Ctrl Break on the debugger and do `sxe ibp` or `sxe ld:bootmgr`, or `sxe ld:*` to break after each module load and now `.reboot`

bootmgr:

```
nt!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction:
fffff800`026df490 cc              int     3
kd> sxe ibp
kd> .reboot
Shutdown occurred at (Sat Apr 17 10:35:32.815 2021 (UTC + 1:00))...unloading all symbol tables.
Waiting to reconnect...
BD: Boot Debugger Initialized
Connected to Windows Boot Debugger 7601 x86 compatible target at (Sat Apr 17 10:35:42.431 2021 (UTC + 1:00)), ptr64 FALSE
Kernel Debugger connection established.  (Initial Breakpoint requested)

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
OK                                             c:\symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: c:\symbols
ReadVirtual() failed in GetXStateConfiguration() first read attempt (error == 997.)
Windows Boot Debugger Kernel Version 7601 UP Free x86 compatible
Machine Name:
Primary image base = 0x00400000 Loaded module list = 0x00491b80
System Uptime: not available
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
bootmgr!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction:
00443914 cc              int     3
kd> lm
start    end        module name
00400000 004ad000   bootmgr    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\bootmgr.pdb\DAAC2D2514AB41E8B3D8B9679BC922CB1\bootmgr.pdb
kd> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 00061c74 0042f31c bootmgr!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction
01 00061e8c 0042f21c bootmgr!vDbgPrintExWithPrefixInternal+0xfe
02 00061e9c 0043f186 bootmgr!DbgPrint+0x11
03 00061eb8 0043f494 bootmgr!BlBdStart+0x9d
04 00061f50 0041f48e bootmgr!BlBdInitialize+0x17e
05 00061f60 0041e9b4 bootmgr!ReinitializeLibrary+0x24
06 00061f6c 00401178 bootmgr!BlInitializeLibrary+0x10
07 00061ff0 00020a9a bootmgr!BmMain+0x178
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
08 00000000 f000ff53 0x20a9a
09 ffffffff 00000000 0xf000ff53
kd> .lastevent
Last event: Load module bootmgr at 00400000
  debugger time: Sat Apr 17 11:18:37.280 2021 (UTC + 1:00)
```

Winload has always been temperamental for me and is hard to break into. `sxe ld:*` or `sxe ibp` often crashes on winload or skips it. The most consistent way is to turn bootdebug on bootmgr off, and then `sxe ibp` breaks into winload.

```
kd> sxe ibp
kd> .reboot
Shutdown occurred at (Sat Apr 17 14:52:05.818 2021 (UTC + 1:00))...unloading all symbol tables.
Waiting to reconnect...
BD: Boot Debugger Initialized
Connected to Windows Boot Debugger 7601 x64 target at (Sat Apr 17 14:52:40.508 2021 (UTC + 1:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Kernel Debugger connection established.
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: c:\symbols
Windows Boot Debugger Kernel Version 7601 UP Free x64
Machine Name:
Primary image base = 0x00000000`002ef000 Loaded module list = 0x00000000`003a19e0
System Uptime: not available
winload!DebugService2+0x5:
00000000`00357055 cc              int     3
kd> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`00183dd8 00000000`002fab04 winload!DebugService2+0x5
00000000`00183de0 00000000`002fb004 winload!BlBdStart+0x154
00000000`00183e40 00000000`0031c82f winload!BlBdInitialize+0x210
00000000`00183f00 00000000`0031bdb2 winload!InitializeLibrary+0x25b
00000000`00183f40 00000000`002f007c winload!BlInitializeLibrary+0x52
00000000`00183f70 00000000`00450d4c winload!OslMain+0x7c
00000000`00183ff0 00000000`00000000 0x450d4c

kd> lm
start             end                 module name
00000000`002ef000 00000000`003b2000   winload    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\winload_prod.pdb\768283CA443847FB8822F9DB1F36ECC51\winload_prod.pdb
kd> .lastevent
Last event: Load module winload.exe at 00000000`002ef000
  debugger time: Sat Apr 17 14:52:40.504 2021 (UTC + 1:00)
```

Similarly, when I debug winload, it crashes when attempting to connect to the nt debugger, so in order to debug nt, I have to disable bootdebug on {current}, and then sxe ibp or sxe ld:nt works.

Comment: Besides, network remote debug could be done after setting proper BCD configs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--dbgsettings